# How to create proper text outline with geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

So the usual way to create text outlines is by creating a text object, `Object data property > Geometry > Bevel > select "round" & increase "depth"`. How would one go about generating a similar look, using the `String to Curves` node?

The most obvious, and also, the only setup I've come across, is this:
[image: String to Curves connected to Curve to Mesh on the "Curve" socket, and Curve Circle on the "Profile Curve" socket]

But this doesn't give a desirable output. It's a bit jagged and uneven, and it becomes more glaring when you increase the thickness of it even further.
[image: Geo. Nodes vs Text + Bevel]

And so.. Is there a better way to do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the handle type to *Align* using a *Set Handle Type* node. The curve also benefits slightly from being subdivided. you can add a *Set Spline Type* node near the beginning to change the type of curve used to display the "text" - not saying you'll use anything other than *Bezier*, but each has a unique look (although poly is probably closest to what you're trying to avoid):

[image: SplineText]

Comment: Hey thanks, this does it! The subdivision also makes it a lot more accurate. Is there a way to "decimate" it afterwards so there's not a lot of geometry where there need not be, like on the parts where the curve path is completely straight?

Comment: That's a good question. The only thing I can think of art the moment is to apply the geometry nodes modifier and then use a decimate modifier - however, that is a destructive solution which may or may not work for you depending on your usage needs.

Comment: Why to apply GN modifier? You can use Decimate modifier just after GN modifier in stack ... I'm more curious if there is an option to generate outline and keep it as curve :) with GN.